# Sums of geometric series

Tags: real-analysis

I must be confused on geometric series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\textrm{some exponent}}{x}^{n}$ since I am under the impression that a series like this does not converge to a sum unless $|x|<1$. My professor assigned a homework problem that reads "Find the sum ..." and the series we are summing is in that exact form but we are never told $|x|<1$.

At this point, I know he likely wants us to start with $1+x+x^2+x^3+... = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and  use that to create a formula for this summation. I can do that, but I don't think this is correct and my professor has stopped responding to emails. I really do hope someone here can help clarify why I can find a sum for this series without $|x|<1$.

Comment: Yes, it only converges for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. That seems to be a tacit assumption.

Comment: I'm not good in computing the sums of divergent series, but certainly the radius of convergence of your series is exactly $|x|<1$. Hard to say why the professor stopped responding without knowing the content of the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find a sum without $|x| \lt 1$ because it diverges.  I would state that at the start of your answer and proceed.  You are correct to use the formula you quote $1+x+x^2+x^3+... = \frac{1}{1-x}$.  Now to get for the exponent $1$, do $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac 1{1-x}\\ \frac d{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac d{dx}\frac 1{1-x}
\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac d{dx}\frac 1{1-x}\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n}=x\frac d{dx}\frac 1{1-x}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance. I'm already writing up my solution and including the additional condition on the radius of convergence for this geometric series.